# Admins On My Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I have just set up a new Minecraft server and was wondering: how do I put myself in creative and no one else?  Is this a Bukkit plugin or can I do this without Bukkit?  Remember I just want me to be in creative.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear: are you the only admin, or are you wanting to make it so that you have more admins and only you can be in Creative mode?

Comment: I want multiple admins in creative

Comment: I think I hear you saying that you want *all* admins to be able to switch to Creative mode without restrictions. Do I understand right?

Comment: @EthanBacon - Your current question says twice you only want a single admin to be in creative.  Please clarify your question because your last comment only confuses people.  Once you clarify your question the downvote will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

This is trivially easy with unmodded Minecraft and the standard Minecraft server from Mojang.

1. Make sure your server is set to use Survival mode by default in `server.properties`. This is the default mode, but if you've been tweaking things make sure this line reads like so:

   ```
   gamemode=0
   ```
2. Add yourself as an op, either by adding your Minecraft username to the file `ops.txt` (while it's not running) or by using the `op <name>` command in the server's console (while it's running) or the `/op <name>` command in the Minecraft client when you're logged in.
3. Log in and use the command `/gamemode c`, which will put you (and only you) in Creative Mode.

You will now be in Creative mode while everyone else will start and stay in Survival mode. Easy!

Your personal gamemode setting is part of the world save, so it will "stick" across logins and server restarts. If you ever want to switch to Survival mode use `/gamemode s`.

Answer (score 3):

Just type

```
/gamemode <Playername> 1
```

and that will set you to creative but will leave everyone else the same.

Comment: Well he is trying to keep creative from the Admins. If they have OP, they can use the same command.

Comment: @Linuxmint Really? That's not how I understand the question. Perhaps it needs clarifying.

Comment: @Linuxmint He just asked how to make himself creative and no one else. That command serves that purpose.

Comment: I see. I assumed that there were several admins with OP and he wanted himself to be the only one with the ability to be in creative.

Comment: @Linuxmint I asked the OP for a clarification. Either reading is plausible, so you might just be right!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is to install Bukkit - Essentials.

http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/

Then create several groups in GroupManager like "Admins" "Moderators" etc.

Then you can give yourself the permission to be in Creative with the following command:

/manuaddp {yourName} essentials.gamemode.creative

And easily remove the permission from any group with:

/mangdelp {groupName} -essentials.gamemode.creative

Comment: do I use that command on the actual server?

Comment: Yes, you use that command from an OP user in-game, or thru the server console.

Comment: okay thatnks for the help

Comment: wait how do I install the Essentials plugin?

Comment: You would need to install Bukkit first thru your FTP. There are some great tutorials you can search for on Google.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
- Make sure that you have

```
 gamemode=0
```

in the server.properties in your Minecraft server folder.
This will make everyone start in survival mode, the normal Minecraft mode.

**Step 2**
- Make sure that you have listed your username in "ops.txt"

In your Minecraft server folder, open the file named "ops.txt" and type your username in it. This will allow you to have complete control over the server.

For example, say your username is "*MinecraftPlayer*". You would want to type "*MinecraftPlayer*" in "ops.txt".

**Step 3**
- Turn on your server, and in chat, type the following:

```
 /gamemode 1
```

This will make you, and only you, enter creative mode. To go back to survival, type:

```
 /gamemode 0
```

---

If you ever want other people to be able to enter a different gamemode, type:

```
 /gamemode <0 or 1> <PlayerNameHere>
```

So to change "Bob"'s mode to creative, I would type:

```
 /gamemode 1 Bob
```

---

If you want to allow other people to change from creative and survival by themselves, type:

```
 /op <PlayerNameHere>
```

So say I want Bob to be able to change his mode without asking me (cause I'm lazy.) I would type:

```
 /op Bob
```

Be careful when "opping" people, because an experienced Minecraft-er can easily attack your server as an "op".